# What do I need to be aware of if I choose to resell property early (in Alberta)?

Tags: canada, real-estate, selling

I have recently made an offer on a home in Alberta. I am curious to know how I might be affected if I choose to sell within the first or second year of owning. I do plan to do upgrades and hopefully turn a profit, though I realize there is risk involved with that strategy. I've heard that there may be taxes involved when I sell so quickly and I have also heard that there may even be laws involved in "flipping" a house. My initial plans were to stay long-term, but it has occurred to me that I could make a profit with some luck and careful planning. What do I need to know in the province of Alberta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have no problem doing this for one home and living in it for one or two years.  There's a recent court case with around six homes bought and sold by the same person in that time frame.  That's what you've probably heard about.  There's no hard and fast rule about when it becomes a business but here are some highlights from that court case.

> Among the criteria developed by the case law, the following are of
>   note:
>
> 1. The nature of the property sold;
> 2. The length of time the taxpayer was in possession as owner of the property;
> 3. The frequency and number of operations carried out by the taxpayer;
> 4. The improvements made by the taxpayer to the property;
> 5. The circumstances surrounding the sale of the property; and
> 6. The taxpayer’s intention at the time the property was acquired, as indicated by the taxpayer’s actions.

[Constantin v. The Queen, 2014 TCC 327 (CanLII)](http://www.canlii.org/en/ca/tcc/doc/2014/2014tcc327/2014tcc327.html)